# Removing Script Error Popups

Tags: c#, javascript, popup, web-crawler

I am working on a security program that amongst other things tries to manipulate webpages to test them for possible Javascript Injections, Cross-Site Scripting etc.

To do so I have the program crawl the webpage and inject code. However, in some occasions this crawling and injecting leads to the following error message.

[image]

Don't get me wrong - I am not asking WHY I get the error message, because that is rather self-explanatory. What I am asking is if there is a way to automatically accept them if they come up.

Some things that are important to note:

- You won't always get the same amount of messages or at the same time
- It is important that they are ACCEPTED (By selecting [Yes])

Any solution would be very much appreciated.

**Update**

- I do not have access to the function that throws the error
- I do not have access to JavaScript, since this is written in C#. Unless I can somehow include Javascript in C# to handle this specific instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx) class, then you can use the following snippet:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Comment: Are you kidding me? How did I miss that function? That is EXACTLY what I am looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try handling error with `window.onerror`. [Reference](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/)

Comment: Just as i was about to post! +1

Comment: I am sorry, I might not have been clear enough. The program is written in C# and I have no access to any javascript coding. The error message is also not thrown from any of my own functions.